# Google Admob didn't show up for the tester when I submit to review

Tags: ios, admob

I am using google Admob for my iOS app. I tested my app on real device and simulator. The ads was showed with the Test banner. However, after I submit to App Store for review. They said:

> We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality.

What should I do now?

Comment: Be sure to remove your test request from your distribution build. Can you add your AdMob code to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Please check few thing with your code -

1. Are you using latest version of Google SDK.
2. Are you configure your app with Google ADmob ?

If above all question is alright , then please check again once more time with your app , if you can see ads on test mode then take screenshot and contact with apple reviewer.